# How do I add a unit suffix to the hours an employee has worked?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, equation

I'm looking for a formula to count hours and set up a shift plan 
My idea is for managers, front of house and back of house to have their own planner.
Where I fall at is when I try to count hours for each staff member BUT also make it legible to the reader when printed

For example 
Staff member 4 does
0830-1600 with an hour break on Monday 
1200-1900 with no break on Tuesday 
I want it to look like 0830-1600, but in the total hours to count out the whole week from the times put in each day [image]

Comment: `Where I fall at is when I try to count hours for each staff member BUT also make it legible to the reader when printed` - so is that in fact a design question?

Comment: No, I can sort all that out, it's if I write the hours like in the picture, I don't know how to put the value from a text field in a format like: 8am-6pm etc

Comment: That depends on what you have in that text filed.

Comment: I think I'm going with `0800-1600`, `1200-2100` etc etc

Comment: Well, you could [split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278528.aspx) at the `-`, take [first two](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251556.aspx) and [last two](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278801.aspx) digits of each part and [construct time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251654.aspx) from them, then [format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx) it in am/pm format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to re-design your calendar. Excel loves raw data to be split out onto separate rows so let's start with that.

This is my end goal - it's a simplified version of yours
[image]

---

### Data

So let's set out the data that will get us there - ***in rows***. For this example, paste the data into cell `A6`:

```
Name    Day      Time In  Time Out  Total
Name 1  09/01/17    08:00   18:00   10:00
Name 1  12/01/17    11:00   15:00   04:00
Name 1  13/01/17    12:00   21:00   09:00
Name 2  10/01/17    08:00   13:00   05:00
Name 2  11/01/17    12:00   20:00   08:00
Name 2  13/01/17    10:00   14:00   04:00
```

And then add another few columns onto the end which will be useful in getting totals and making the table more readable
[image]

*Unique ID* is created simply by concatenating name and day : `=A7&B7`. And the *Time String* uses the `TEXT` function

```
=UPPER(TEXT(C7,"hAM/PM")&"/"&TEXT(D7,"hAM/PM"))
```

---

### Table

Create your table in `A1:F3` (like below). No need for manual shift data but do put your people and dates headings in:
[image]

Use this simple formula in cell `B2` and drag down and across to populate shift data

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2&B$1,$F$6:$G$12,2,0),"OFF")
```

Similarly, you can use this formula for the `total hours`

```
=SUMIF($A$7:$A$12,$A2,$E$7:$E$12)*24
```

---

### Result

The final result is below, and can be easily manipulated for more people/ dates, etc.

[image]

*If you have questions about any of these formulas/ techniques -- do ask*

Comment: This is fantastic. I've set it up so where you have `B7:B12` I have every day, as it will be easier for management to enter the times if they have every day. This means I always have a Time string, so let's say `B3` should say `OFF` it actually says `12AM/12AM`. Any way to fix this?

Comment: You should be able to change your formula in `G7` to this:  `=IF(E7=0,"OFF",UPPER(TEXT(C7,"hAM/PM")&"/"&TEXT(D7,"hAM/PM")))`