# How to display dates a person is working

Tags: excel

I have created a basic rota that I can input data into blank cells which highlight depending on the code. See images below

[image]

When I type the code DW it will highlight blue, I want to display these dates in a seperate table so staff can easily see what dates they should be working. e.g. Joe Bloggs is woking on the 2nd April 2018 so I want to show this date in the cell below so it's easy for them to see.

[image]

Would this be possible using the LOOKUP function and if so how would you do this?

Comment: You're doing this the wrong way around. Excel likes to *use* data to *create* reports. You are trying to *use* a report to *create* data. So: type the dates in manually, and have the report conditionally formatted based on that.

Comment: Here is a similar question about rotas which needed to be reworked in the way I described above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41538053/how-do-i-add-a-unit-suffix-to-the-hours-an-employee-has-worked/41538579#41538579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with `INDEX` `MATCH`. I've entered the following into cell `B8` This is an array formula so it is entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=IFNA(INDEX($C$2:$G$2, MATCH(1,($C3:$G3="DW")*(COUNTIF($A8:A8,$C$2:$G$2)=0),0)),"")
```

If using a version of Excel pre 2013 `IFNA` won't work and so you can use `IFERROR` instead

[image: Results]

Comment: Thank you for this Tom but when using this formula it's coming back as an error #NAME?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? If pre 2013 then change `IFNA` to `IFERROR`

Comment: Thank you, this worked great. Do I put the same code in the second cell and just change it to C8?

And do it for the rest of the cells below for other staff?

Comment: You can't see it but in my example I've actually dragged the formula from `B8` all the way along to `G8` (it returns nothing as it can't find anymore days). You should be able to drag (bottom right hand of cell) all the way along, and down for other employees as well. The only change you'll need to make is `($C$3:$G$3="DW")` to `($C3:$G3="DW")`. I'll update this in my answer as well

Comment: I would, however also recommend restructuring your data as to how CallumDA proposed in the comments

Comment: Thank you so much for this, my boss will be over the moon. I hope this isn't cheeky but just for learning purposes. Where you have put $A8:$A8 what does this refer to as to me it looks like it's looking at the person name?

Comment: I don't think it's what I want to achieve, this is so my boss can see the cells clearly and place the days she wants a member of staff to cover a shift. It's to avoid her using paper. It's not a normal rota of when staff work, it's to cover a particular shift and it makes it easier for her to see the cells shaded in and cuts down on her time.

Comment: The `$A8:A8` will expand as you drag the formula across, so in `C8` it would be `$A8:B8`. This is to provide a unique list of the values that are returned - It makes sure the value hasn't already been included. In `B8` I want it to return 0 so I set it on `A8`, then in `C8` I don't want it to include the contents of `B8` and so on. The persons name is irrelevant for this it's just a handy point to start so that the formula will auto-expand

Comment: I can understand that, but it would make it easier for both (and probably other reports) to start in that format.

Comment: No problem, I will look into that. Thank you again for all your help

Comment: [This link might explain the `COUNTIF` bit better](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list) I've just modified this to expand it so that it is criteria based as well (returns only the `DW` criteria cells)